# Docusaurus: npm run serve reloaded page not rendered

Tags: docusaurus

I have a docosaurus page running. It works fine. I use

'npm run build'

and

'npm run serve'

to deploy it. The app runs fine, but when I go to any page that is not on root and I refresh it, I get:

Index of  build/ Quick Intro/ quick1.2/

instead of the rendered page.

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in old versions of Docusaurus v2. If you look at the screenshots in the following bug report and PR, they show the same "Index of build/..." page:

- Bug Report: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/6699
- Fixed by PR: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/6701

I had the same issue when using Docusaurus v2.0.0-beta.15 and upgrading to Docusaurus v2.0.0-beta.17 fixed it.

According to the CHANGELOG.md, **it should also be fixed in v2.0.0-beta.16**:

> ### 2.0.0-beta.16 (2022-02-25)
>
> ...
>
> ##### Bug Fix
>
> ...
>
> - `docusaurus`
>
>   - [#6701](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/6701) fix(cli): disable directory listing in serve ([@Josh-Cena](https://github.com/Josh-Cena))

Source: [Docusaurus/CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/a4e37c40540b73782d6fabc012bc2ef15fa298b3/CHANGELOG.md?plain=1#L132-L133)